# Sqlloader when clause to include null

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am trying to load some data into a table, however the data source has a footer record which I want to remove and also NULL values which I DO want to be loaded

my control file currently has:

```
echo "WHEN field1 <> 'FOOTER'"
```

but this is discarding the null records (all others are working as expected).

Is there a way to include an 'or' operator, or to get this running as a two step load inside a single control file e.g. step 1. process all records except the 'FOOTER' step 2 - process all NULL records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue:
The solution was to treat it as two seperate loads so my control file looks like:

```
echo "APPEND INTO TABLE table.t1"
echo "WHEN (1:1)=' '"
echo "("
....
echo ")"
echo "INTO TABLE table.t1"
echo "WHEN field != 'FOOTER'"
echo "("
....
```

This then processes the NULL records and then the non-footer ones. I was having difficulty matching up the fixed length of field1 with the NULL values - however a single length check is what was required.

Hope this answers the question for anyone else struggling also.

Comment: There is also a "LOAD = n" component to the OPTION clause that allows you to specify the number of rows to load. If you used LOAD = <number of lines in your file - 1> that would skip the footer too. See the OPTION clause here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1004788

Comment: Yes I looked into this however the number of records is variable and I also looked into removing the footer from the input file (redirected to another file to preserve the original) however these weren't the approaches I wanted to take as I wanted to keep the automated load process as similar between tables as possible - with the only difference being the control files used - to ease with debugging and enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
load data
infile ...
into table ...
...
...
when some_column != 'FOOTER'
...
fields terminated by ', '
```

Comment: I have tried this and it didn't work.I can just remove the when clause and it does process everything as expected (the single footer record is discarded) however I don't want a discarded file every single time this process runs if I can help it. I had: echo "APPEND INTO TABLE table.t1"
echo "WHEN field1 != 'FOOTER'"
echo "fields terminated by ', '"
echo "("
echo "    field1      POSITION (01:07)  \"REPLACE(UPPER(:field1), ' ')\","
echo "    field2   POSITION (09:14) \"DECODE(:field2 ,'000000', NULL, TO_DATE(:field2 , 'DDMMYY'))\" ,"   ...